# How to Extract the Current URL and ID in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about getting the current URL using jquery, or more specifically, getting an ID on the end of it?

For example, I have product.php#tab-2. What I want to get from it is just the '#tab-2' part.

I have tried 'window.location.pathname' but that will only return '/product.php'

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this:

```
alert(window.location.href); // will give you the full url
alert(window.location.hash); // will give you the hash (#) value
```

See the Mozilla docs at [window.location - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Answer (score 1):

You want window.location.hash

Answer (score 0):

Use jqUrl plugin (http://www.oakcitygraphics.com/jquery/jqURL/jqURLdemo.html) to retrieve the full current url, then strip the window.location.pathname part.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

To actually assign to a variable, use the following;

```
var url = window.location.href;

var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);
```

Note that if your url is in this format /product.php/3 , then you can use the above code, just change the character is the lastIndexOf function.